# how to remove index.php without other urls and have a referral 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, opencart, opencart-3

I am using this code to remove index.php for opencart. However, there are other addresses:

/index.php?route=account/register

Of course the code starts to delete index.php everywhere.
My goal is to remove it (index.php) for SEO because of duplicate content.

**I use this**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: What actually is the question here? Are you getting an error or incorrect redirect with your directives? (Have you removed `index.php` from the URLs in your HTML source?)

Answer (score 0):

To use SEO URLs, apache module mod-rewrite must be installed and you need to rename the `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`.

Then inside Opencart's admin go to `System > Settings > Edit Store > Settings > Server > Use SEO URLs > YES`.